# `nameof()` does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, nameof

So what I am trying to do is quite simple.

I am trying to run a `nameof()` on some of the primitive types as I need these constants for a certain requirement.

But when I try to do that for eg `nameof(bool)` it says that `nameof()` does not exist in the current context.

And this seems to be the case with all Synonyms?

Is there any other way to do this or am I missing something.

what I am trying to do is

```
public static readonly string BoolConstant= nameof(bool);
```

Expected result:

```
BoolConstant= "bool";
```

Will I have to write all these constants down?

Comment: Could be that your language version is old-ish. `nameof()` was not introduced till C# 6.0 I believe.

Comment: I have the latest stable c# and that's a little obvious man. I am using nameof's all over the place in my code right now. Thanks for your reply anyway

Comment: @FreakyAli: I suspect you do not get the point of `nameof`. It is to express that you want the name of some symbolic element *which can change upon refactoring*.  There's no point in doing `nameof(bool)` because *there is no way to refactor `bool` to be some other keyword*.  If you want the string `"bool"` then just type that string.

Comment: "as I need these constants for a certain requirement" this always sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). *Why* do you need this? Maybe there's a better solution for what you *actually* need to do.

Comment: @FreakyAli: No, it's not "a little obvious" - we didn't have the information that you're using nameof elsewhere, and this is exactly the error you *would* get if you were using an old version of C#. Please give a little more respect to those who are trying to help you.

Comment: Additionally, I'm confused as to why you're getting that error at all. When I try using your exact code, the error is "error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'bool'" - which isn't the same thing at all (and is much clearer about the cause).

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, that is weird a specific error makes more sense but that is what i get

Comment: @JHBonarius Basically I have a situation where I have to parse the data based on the datatype that is sent from the API as a part of the string. Now my API is not in C# so I basically sent bool from the API for boolean parsing. What i realised later on is that nameof was not working with keywords. So now i changed my API to match what i can do i.e. nameof(Boolean)

Comment: Which version of the C# compiler are you using? (And is this the MS compiler, or Mono, or something else?) Can you provide a [mcve] rather than just a single line? If you change that line of code to `Boolean` instead of `bool`, in exactly the same context, does the error go away?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it goes away when I do that and that is what I did actually. And I am using Xamarin Forms .Net Standard with .Net Framework 4.7.xxx so my C# compiler must be what v7.3 I suppose.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Sorry if I sounded rude to you in any way that was not my intention and thanks for the reply it was really appreciatted!

Comment: "so my C# compiler must be what v7.3 I suppose" - I'd be more interested in what version it *says* it is, e.g. when you build. But it's probably not worth pursuing. (If you're interested, you might want to try the same exercise with a simple console app - it's entirely possible that working with Xamarin is doing something different.)

Comment: @FreakyAli It's cool. I learned something new today according to the answers listed!

Comment: @JonSkeet I actually did so it seems to give me the same error! Which I agree is really weird. In any case, I am going to take a look into this and get back to you soon!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nameof` is only applicable to Type and its members and not the keywords, `bool` is keyword, basically bool is short for `Boolean`.

Try `nameof(Boolean)`, it works.

As per [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#nameof-expressions),

```
nameof_expression
    : 'nameof' '(' named_entity ')'
    ;

named_entity
    : simple_name
    | named_entity_target '.' identifier type_argument_list?
    ;

named_entity_target
    : 'this'
    | 'base'
    | named_entity 
    | predefined_type 
    | qualified_alias_member
    ;
```

`named_entity` can be `simple_name`, and `simple_name` can be identifier with type argument list, nowhere in this Grammar it says that `named_entity` can be `predefined_type`, `int, bool` etc fall under `predefined_type`.

So as per this grammar,

`nameof(this)` is not acceptable, but `nameof(this.Property)` is, same way no keywords can be used inside `nameof(..)`. I don't know the reason but it seems unnecessary and also it would make compiler more complicated to distinguish between grammar that uses keywords.

**`nameof` itself is also a keyword**

List of keywords in C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Answer (score 3):

`bool` is a keyword and you can use like this:

```
typeof(bool).Name;
```

or

```
nameof(Boolean)
```

both result is equal  ->  "Boolean"

Comment: @FreakyAli: `bool` is a keyword.

Comment: Yeah, I remembered that but its also a synonym, which is actually the reason why nameof does not work. Correct me if I am wrong @EricLippert

Comment: @FreakyAli: `nameof` takes as its operand *a name*, but `bool` is not a name; it's a keyword.